# jQuery script doesn't open iframe on click

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am working on a jQuery script to use in a WordPress widget. When the user clicks on the "upload" button, an iframe should pop open with an image uploader. Right now, that button doesn't work. The iframe doesn't open. Here is my script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

jQuery('#upload_image_button').click(function() {
 formfield = jQuery('#upload_image').attr('name');
 tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=image&TB_iframe=true');
 return false;
});

window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
 imgurl = jQuery('img',html).attr('src');
 jQuery('#upload_image').val(imgurl);
 tb_remove();
}

});
```

Here is the input field and the button:

```
<input id="upload_image" class="widefat" type="text" size="36" name="upload_image" value="<?php echo esc_url( $image ); ?>" />
<input id="upload_image_button" type="button" value="Upload Image" />
```

Comment: Give us the code for your tb_show function?

Comment: Should there be a separate function for that? I was following this tutorial  http://www.webmaster-source.com/2010/01/08/using-the-wordpress-uploader-in-your-plugin-or-theme/

Comment: tb_show is not an in-built function.  So if you don't have that, that is likely why it isn't working.  I would check to make sure you have the function by executing it in the console.

Comment: `tb_show` is a built in function of the native WP thickbox!

Comment: Well, I have the thickbox script loaded just fine so the tb_show function should be loaded as well.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your console?